# UISlider not holding values in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uislider

[image: what I start off with]

For whatever reason.. when I move past it (go down), the slider gets weird and it graphically changes and doesnt retain a value.

[image: What I end up with]

Notice you can see a shadow of where it was. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer....

All your custom "initWithFrame" code like this:

```
UISlider *theSlider =  [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55,20,220,45)] autorelease];
theSlider.maximumValue=10;
theSlider.minimumValue=0;       
    [cell addSubview:theSlider];
```

Has to be inside this block, or else every time it will try to redraw:

```
 if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; 
 }
```

I had it like this:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; 

UISlider *theSlider =  [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55,20,220,45)] autorelease];
theSlider.maximumValue=10;
theSlider.minimumValue=0;       
    [cell addSubview:theSlider];
 }
```

Comment: its true if you have any UI Object that the user can change than this is the only simple way to achieve it.